# how to copy std::vector<const char*> into void*?

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector<const char*> v` vector fully initiated with strings. How do I copy it into an initialized `void*`?

```
int main() {
 std::vector<const char*> v;
 v.push_back("abc");
 v.push_back("def"); 
 void* b = malloc(6);

 // how to copy v in to b?
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Better question: why are you using `char*` and `malloc` in C++?

Comment: You're confused. Your vector is of size 2 and contains two pointers. You don't need six bytes for two pointers, you need 16 (assuming you're on a 64 bit system).

Comment: @PSkocik He wants to put the strings of the `const char*`s into `b`, not the pointers themselves.

Comment: The memory pointed to by `b` is *not* initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the range based for statement. For example

```
void *p = b;
for ( const char *s : v )
{
   size_t n = std::strlen( s );
   std::memcpy( p, s, n );
   p = ( char * )p + n;
}
```

The same can be done with standard algorithm `std::accumulate` declared in header `<numeric>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<const char*> v;

    v.push_back( "abc" );
    v.push_back( "def" ); 
    void *b = new char[6];  

    auto p = std::accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), b,
                              []( void *acc, const char *s ) -> void *
                              {
                                  size_t n = std::strlen( s );
                                  return ( ( char * )std::memcpy( acc, s, n ) + n );
                              } );

    std::cout.write( (const char * )b , ( const char * )p - ( const char * )b );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
abcdef
```

Take into account that it would be better to write

```
void* b = new char[6];
```

Comment: I got a warning for doing pointer arithmetic but it works. So thank you.

Comment: @cody See my updated post. You have to cast the pointer to char *

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the vector moving your pointer along by the string length each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < v.length(); i++) {
    memcpy(b + currentIndex, v[i], strlen(v[i]));
    currentIndex += strlen(v[i]);
}
```

Something like that, may not work I didn't test it.

And if you want to use `b` as a string, you need to put a `0` on the end.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 std::vector<const char*> v;
 v.push_back("abc");
 v.push_back("def"); 
 void* b = malloc(6);
int l = strlen(v[0]);
memcpy(b, v[0], l);
l = strlen(v[1]);
memcpy(b+l, v[1], l);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most C++-like way I can think of.  It doesn't use any C-style string manipulation or memory management functions and it is as safe as can be.  Downside is that a temporary buffer is allocated and released without actual need.

The following headers are used in this example.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

Now, the first version (which I prefer) allocates a buffer of the correct size and returns it wrapped in a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` from which the caller can then extract the buffer and implicitly cast it to `void *` if needed.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<char[]>
concatenate(const std::vector<const char *>& words)
{
  std::string buffer {};
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> dup_uptr {};
  for (const auto word : words)
    buffer += word;
  dup_uptr.reset(new char[buffer.size() + 1]);
  buffer.copy(dup_uptr.get(), buffer.size());
  dup_uptr.get()[buffer.size()] = '\0';
  return dup_uptr;
}
```

The second version takes the destination buffer and its size as parameters and copies the concatenated string there.  This can obviously fail if the buffer happens to be too small and it is also less safe since we might make a mistake and pass the wrong buffer size.  For convenience, it returns a `char *` pointer to the string or a `nullptr` if the buffer was too small.

```cpp
char *
concatenate(const std::vector<const char *>& words,
            void *const dest,
            const std::size_t size)
{
  char * dest_chars = static_cast<char *>(dest);
  std::string buffer {};
  for (const auto word : words)
    buffer += word;
  // If we cannot copy the whole thing, copy nothing at all.
  if (buffer.size() >= size)
    return nullptr;
  buffer.copy(dest_chars, buffer.size());
  dest_chars[buffer.size()] = '\0';
  return dest_chars;
}
```

The two functions can be used like this:

```cpp
int
main()
{
  const std::vector<const char*> vec {"abc", "def"};
  // first version
  {
    auto concat = concatenate(vec);
    std::cout << concat.get() << std::endl;
  }
  // second version
  {
    auto tempbuff = std::get_temporary_buffer<void>(100);
    if (auto concat = concatenate(vec, tempbuff.first, tempbuff.second))
      std::cout << concat << std::endl;
    std::return_temporary_buffer(tempbuff.first);
  }
  return 0;
}
```